# Can I bind a value in a RAZOR component to a value in a String array?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, .net-5, razor-components

I have a page with a form in it. I want to give the users the ability to add a custom input if they would like. I would also like the ability to quickly change the number of these custom inputs.

For Example:

```
    Name: ____________________
    Phone Number: ____________
    email:  __________________
[ ] Some Option
[ ] Another Option
[ ] custom input 1: __________
[ ] custom input 2: __________
[ ] custom input 3: __________
 .
 .
 .
[ ] custom input N: __________
```

The checkboxes in front add that input to the submitted form data.

This is what I tried

```
<div>
    @for(int iterator=0; iterator<customInputs.Length; iterator++){
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <span class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" id="@(customInputs[iterator] + "Checkbox")" name="@(customInputs[iterator] + "Checkbox")" value="InputCustom@(customInputs[iterator] + "Checkbox")" aria-label="Input Custom @(customInputs[iterator])Check" @onchange="eventArgs => { gatherData(true, customInputs[iterator]); }" />
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="@(customInputs[iterator] + "Text")" name="@(customInputs[iterator] + "Text")" placeholder="Custom Input @(iterator+1)" aria-label="@(customInputs[iterator] + "Text")" @bind="customInputs[iterator]" />
            </span>
        </label>
    }
</div>

@code {
    IList<String> checkedBoxes = new List<String>();

    String[] customInputs = new String[NumericConstants.MAX_CUSTOM_INPUTS];

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<NumericConstants.MAX_CUSTOM_INPUTS; i++){
            customInput[i] = ("customInput" + i.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void gatherData(bool subject, String selection)
    {
        checkedBoxes.Add(selection);
    }
}
```

When I run this, this is what happens:

1. The input fields are already filled in with "customInputN" even though I don't have a "value" set.
2. When I change one of the inputs, it always reverts back to "customInputN"
3. When I leave that `input type="text"` field, I get the exception `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`
4. I set a breakpoint at the `for` loop in the HTML, and it appears to traverse the loop twice.

Is what I am trying even possible?

---

**EDIT:**

As requested, here is the HTML output for if `MAX_CUSTOM_INPUTS` is 3:

```
<span class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
    <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" id="customInputs0Checkbox" name="customInputs0Checkbox" value="InputCustomCustomcustomInputs0Checkbox" aria-label="Input Custom Custom customInputs0Check">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="customInputs0Text" name="customInputs0Text" placeholder="Custom Input 1" aria-label="customInputs0Text">
</span>

<span class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
    <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" id="customInputs1Checkbox" name="customInputs1Checkbox" value="InputCustomCustomcustomInputs1Checkbox" aria-label="Input Custom Custom customInputs1Check">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="customInputs1Text" name="customInputs1Text" placeholder="Custom Input 2" aria-label="customInputs1Text">
</span>

<span class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
    <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" id="customInputs2Checkbox" name="customInputs2Checkbox" value="InputCustomCustomcustomInputs2Checkbox" aria-label="Input Custom Custom customInputs2Check">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="customInputs2Text" name="customInputs2Text" placeholder="Custom Input 3" aria-label="customInputs2Text">
</span>
```

Comment: Did you intend to have `customInput[i] = (` in `void OnInitialized()`? Is it supposed to be `customInputs[i] = (`?

Comment: Wow, that's some weird behavior. I'm guessing there's some issue with open/closed tags/quotes. Can you view the HTML source and add it to your question?

Comment: @JohnWu I have added the generated HTML. Thank you.

Comment: @DekuDesu Just like I have `String name;` bound to `@bind="name"` and `String email;` bound to `@bind="email"` and `String phonenumber;` bound to `@bind="phonenumber"`, I would like `customInputs[0]` bound to `@bind="customInputs[0]"`.

Comment: @JohnWu I do, indeed, understand how a placeholder works. Did I miss something? Did I put a parenthesis or something where it should not be? Why do you ask?

Comment: These two sentences suggest that you are working with the placeholder text and not the input text: *The input fields are already filled in with "customInputN" even though I don't have a "value" set. When I change one of the inputs, it always reverts back to "customInputN"*

Comment: I know what `PLACEHOLDER` is, and I know what it does. However, when I run my app, the placeholder text is in there as if I had pre-set a `VALUE` into the text input. Meaning, I can edit the text there, and placeholder is not editable, which makes me thing I have done something wrong or what I am trying to do is not possible.